# Angular JS Karma Testing 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ngModel.$setViewValue(undefined)')

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a directive and I keep getting 
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ngModel.$setViewValue(undefined)')

What am I doing wrong?

The directive is to clear hidden details:

```
testApp.directive("clearhidden", [ '$compile', '$parse', function ($compile, $parse) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope:true,
    require: ['ngModel'],
    link: function(scope, tElement, attrs, ngModel) {

            if(!ngModel){
                return;
            }
            //clear model values for hidden fields
            var initValue = undefined;
            if (attrs.ngInit) {
                 initValue = $parse(attrs.ngInit)(scope);                    
            }
            scope.$watch(function() {                   
                return tElement.is(":visible");
            }, function(visible) {
                 if (visible) {
                    if (ngModel.$modelValue == undefined) {
                         if (initValue != undefined) {
                             ngModel.$setViewValue(initValue);
                             ngModel.$render();
                         }
                     }
                 } else {
                    var isDisabled = false;                        
                    if (attrs.ngDisabled) {
                         isDisabled = $parse(attrs.ngDisabled)(scope);
                    }
                    if (!isDisabled) {                          
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(undefined);
                        ngModel.$render();
                    }
                 }
            });
    }
};
}]);
```

The karma being executed is :

```
   describe("directive-ClearHidden", function() {               
    var $compile;
    var $rootScope;     
    beforeEach(module('testApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
      $compile = _$compile_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

   it('process directive', function() {
       $rootScope.myObject="TESTER2";          
       var element = $compile(angular.element('<form name="form"><input ng-  model="myObject" clearhidden/></form>'))($rootScope);        
       $rootScope.$digest();           
     });
  });
```

Can you please tell me why I get the error at ngModel.$setViewValue(undefined); ?

Thanks

Comment: Show your karma config too, please.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with karma config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive you need to do:-

```
link: function(scope, tElement, attrs, ctrls) {
      var ngModel = ctrls[0]; //<-- Get ngModelController from array of controller(s)
```

Since you have specified ngModel as a required array, `require: ['ngModel'],` the controller argument of the linking function will be an array of controller(s) (In your case only ngModelController) actually, not just the ngModel or you could change it to `require:'ngModel'`.

From Documentation

> When a directive requires a controller, it receives that controller as the fourth argument of its link function. Taking advantage of this, myPane can call the addPane function of myTabs.
>
> If multiple controllers are required, the require option of the directive can take an array argument. The corresponding parameter being sent to the link function will also be an array.

[Plnkr with Array of controllers](http://plnkr.co/edit/QwUK7v?p=preview)

[Plnkr w/o array of controllers](http://plnkr.co/edit/JzflaO?p=preview)